# Python pygame, how would i add a border for the player?

Tags: python

```
import pygame
import time
import random
from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit
pygame.init()


# import images
gameicon = pygame.image.load('carcon.png')
background = pygame.image.load('bentrans.jpg')
player = pygame.image.load('kevin.jpg')
player = pygame.transform.scale(player,(40, 40))
#--------------------------------------------------

# main size of program
size = width, height = 600, 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
#screen_size = Rect(600,400)
#-------------------------------------------------

#colours
black = (0,0,0)

white = (255,255,255)

blue =(53, 115, 255)

red = (200,0,0)

green = (0, 200, 0)

bright_red = (255,0,0)

bright_green = (0,255,0)

# -----------------------------------------------


background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (600,400))  # format picture size

screen.blit(background, [0, 0])
pygame.display.set_caption('rip')
pygame.display.set_icon(gameicon)
screenSurf = pygame.Surface(size)
pygame.display.flip()   # updates program to show image


x, y = 150, 353
MOVE_RIGHT = 1
MOVE_LEFT = 2
MOVE_UP = 3
MOVE_DOWN = 4
direction = 0

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == QUIT:
            exit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_LEFT:              # controls
                direction = MOVE_LEFT
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                direction = MOVE_RIGHT
            elif event.key == K_UP:
                direction = MOVE_UP
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                direction = MOVE_DOWN

        elif event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                direction = 0
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                direction = 0
            elif event.key == K_UP:
                direction = 0
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                direction = 0



    if(direction == MOVE_LEFT):
        x-=0.5                                  # copy to add a y change
    elif(direction == MOVE_RIGHT):     
        x+=0.5
    elif(direction == MOVE_UP):
        y-=0.5
    elif(direction == MOVE_DOWN):
        y+=0.5

    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(player, (x, y))
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Hi there, i wanted to ask for some help over a small graphical game I'm creating. My question is if anyone could help me with putting a border around the graphic window so that the image (player) can not leave. I have looked already online but could not a find a working solution. ALL help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add two lines that ensure the player never moves out of bounds:

```
x = min(maximum_value_border_x, max(0, x))
y = min(maximum_value_border_y, max(0, y))
```

where maximum_value_border for x is 600 and for y 400

Comment: Thank you very much for the help

Comment: you can use the variables you mentioned earlier (width and height) instead, i just used these names to make clear what they mean ;)